# datatable row-reorder stops working with column sort

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable in my jsfiddle below with a working row-reorder event.

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/dszyxfj3/6/

I added row-reorder to get the feature where the first column '#' always counts in order correctly even if I drag my 'Ashton Cox' row to the bottom of the table, the '#' column count will be updated via this event handler:

```
//row-reorder event
table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
    var result = 'Reorder started on row: '+edit.triggerRow.data()[1]+'<br>';

    for ( var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        var rowData = table.row( diff[i].node ).data();

        result += rowData[1]+' updated to be in position '+
            diff[i].newData+' (was '+diff[i].oldData+')<br>';
    }

    console.log(result );
} );
```

I want this row-reordering event to work even when I click the 'Audio' column header, which sorts the table's rows based on the audio field alphabetically. But when I click the audio column to sort the table, it breaks the row-reordering, and causes the '#' column to be out of order like in my pic below:

[image]

I added an event listener for when the audio sort column is clicked:

```
 //audio sort clicked
$(`#upload_99_audioCol`).on('click', function(event){
    console.log('audio sort clicked')
    //NEED TO CALL ROW-REORDER event somehow
})
```

is there some way I can call my row-reorder event handler whenever I click the audio column, so that my '#' column numbers are always in order?

thanks

Comment: nevermind, found this exact issue talked about here: http://live.datatables.net/woqujumi/1/edit

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46889/row-reordering-after-sorting